# How can I set or mock a variable from a test file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a file that looks like this:

```
prob = 0.05

def calculate_func(arg1, arg2):
    if random.random > prob:
        # Do stuff
    else:
        # Do other things

# Lots more functions
```

And a test file like this:

```
from my_project import calculate_func

def test_calculate_func():
    arg1, arg2 = 1, 2
    assert calculate_func(arg1, arg2) == 'Desired value'
```

But currently the test file imports `error_prob` from the main file. I want to be able to set, or mock, `error_prob` from the test file to test different behaviours. How can I do this?

I don't want to pass `error_prob` into `calculate_func`, because `error_prob` is used by every function in that file.

Comment: Import the variable, assign another value to it. What is the issue?

Comment: @Goyo, that won't work. Reassign prob in the test file, the test file calls calculate_func(), calculate_func() uses the prob defines in the main file.

Comment: Oh, you need to import the module, not the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reassign module-scoped variables by importing the module.

```
import my_project

myproject.prob = 0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to pass error_prob into calculate_func, because error_prob is used by every function in that file.

If you need to inject a dependency, then you need to inject it. One possibility that might simplify things is to move those functions into a class, and set the `error_prob` implementation as a member when you instantiate it.